# Is there a way to let device A make a call from device B via bluetooth?

Tags: android

I'm new in the Android app developing world and I was wondering if this is possible.  Let's say device A has a button named "Call", and when you click the button it will make device B to make a call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its not possible in android. I guess you saw this feature on Samsung Galaxy Player, if I am not wrong. But the thing is Samsung Galaxy Player is a product like ipod which doesn't have facility of sim card/calling. You can handle that feature using bluetooth api for that device. So unfortunately, there is no such functionality exists in normal devices.